# How to use button in ion list item and perfom action for the button and list separately

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am having an list item in which each list item has an button based on a condition. If I click the button it should show popup and if I click the list item it should go to next page but what happens is if I click the button it shows the popup as well as in background it goes to the next page can anyone tell me how to handle this.

Html:

```
<ion-list class="trans-item">
        <div class="FramerList list" ng-repeat="bill in vm.bills | filter: vm.search">

          <a class="item item-icon-left" ng-if="bill.bill_paid==='true'" ng-click="vm.gotoBillDetail(bill)">
            <i class="icon ion-checkmark-circled"></i>
            {{"bno_message" | translate}} {{ bill.bill_no }}
          </a>

          <a class="item item-icon-left item-button-right" ng-if="bill.bill_paid==='false'" ng-click="vm.gotoBillDetail(bill)">
            <i class="icon ion-close-circled"></i>
            {{"bno_message" | translate}} {{ bill.bill_no }}
            <button class="button button-small billbook-button" ng-click="vm.billpaid(bill)">{{"farmerbillpaid_message" | translate}}</button>
          </a>
        </div>
    </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
<ion-list class="trans-item">
            <div class="FramerList list" ng-repeat="bill in vm.bills | filter: vm.search">

              <a class="item item-icon-left" ng-if="bill.bill_paid==='true'" ng-click="vm.gotoBillDetail(bill)">
                <i class="icon ion-checkmark-circled"></i>
                {{"bno_message" | translate}} {{ bill.bill_no }}
              </a>

              <a class="item item-icon-left item-button-right" ng-if="bill.bill_paid==='false'" ng-click="vm.gotoBillDetail(bill)">
                <i class="icon ion-close-circled"></i>
                {{"bno_message" | translate}} {{ bill.bill_no }}                   
              </a>
 <button class="button button-small billbook-button" ng-click="vm.billpaid(bill)">{{"farmerbillpaid_message" | translate}}</button>
            </div>
        </ion-list>
```

Comment: the button comes out of the item how can i make the button inside the list item itself.

Comment: can you create plunker or demo here so i can edit that easily.